# Como exibir ou fazer o download de qualquer arquivo em PDF no WebView?

Tags: android, webview

Tentei encontrar algumas soluções para o problema. Mas há apenas códigos que baixam um arquivo específico.

Tenho um site que abre em uma webview. Na página há diversos PDFs. Preciso de um código que baixe ou exiba os arquivos.

Segue o código que estou utilizando para webview:

public class AmbienteAula extends Activity {

```
private WebView webViewAmbienteAula1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ambiente_aula);

    String url = "http://www.meusite.com";
    WebView view = (WebView)
            this.findViewById(R.id.webViewAmbienteAula);
    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.loadUrl(url);


}


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
    WebView view = (WebView)
            this.findViewById(R.id.webViewAmbienteAula);
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && view.canGoBack()){
        view.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);


}
```

}

Comment: Eu já fiz, mas não me lembro. Sei que o próprio webview tem um evento. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069050/download-file-inside-webview

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o setDownloadListener.

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
        String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
        long contentLength) {
            Request request = new Request( Uri.parse(url));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "myPDFfile.pdf"); 
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);        
     }
 });
```

Veja [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517141/how-i-can-enable-to-download-pdf-via-webview) uma implementação bacana, espero que te ajude.